# Raspberry Pi RetroPie GPIO Shutdown

Tags: gpio, python, retropie

I'm trying to make an arcade cabinet with my Raspberry Pi and I want to make a physical shutdown button for it. I can do this with the GPIO, I even wrote a python script to do it:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
while True:
    print GPIO.input(17)
    if(GPIO.input(17) == False):
        os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have a switch connected to GRD and to PIN17, that way when I press the button it shutdowns. The problem is I want the script to be running 24/7 so that whenever I push the button it shutdowns! How can I do that?

Note: I'm running [RetroPie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/)

Comment: Just have it start a bootup. Just reference it inside `/etc/rc.local` by adding something like `/home/pi/yourscript.py`